# How to add page detail values to a SharePoint footer

Tags: html, field, sharepoint-2013

I am a novice in SharePoint and I'm updating a company intranet. I want to add a footer to each page (which I've already done manually) but I want to populate the page 'Contact' person's name and 'Date updated' in the footer for each page. The data is displaying in each page's properties--I just don't know how to map the data values into the footer. I don't have SharePoint Designer so I was hoping there is some code I can add to the html or maybe some Javascript I can add to generate these values.

I've looked up numerous blogs on the web but nothing seems to be addressing exactly what I need. They mention web parts and snippets but these do not appear to be what I need.

Example of footer required:
"If you have any questions about this page, please contact [page "contact" name]. This page was last updated on ["date modified"]."

I would like the unique page details to be populated into the footer for each page automatically (ie once I map the required fields).

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using Javascript then you can add jQuery (to master page or layout, or directly to the page... depends on the output you want) and add your custom JS file the same way in which you can use the `_spPageContextInfo` object to get the default page context info.

From this object you can get the page Id and then from it you can do a REST call to SharePoint API to get all columns (to get user column data like title or mail you need to 'expand' this column in rest call).

For your case I would do this kind of script:

```
var getPageProps = function() {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            url:
                _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl +
                "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items(" +
                _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId +
                ')?$select=*,PublishingContact/Title&$expand=PublishingContact',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { Accept: 'application/json; odata=verbose' },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(
                    'If you have any questions about this page, please contact ' +
                        data.d.PublishingContact.Title +
                        '. This page was last updated on ' +
                        data.d.Modified
                );
                // other logic goes here 
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.error('getPageProps ajax call error-> ' + data);
            }
        });
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error('getPageProps error -> ' + ex.message);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    getPageProps();
});
```

and I would modify the used MasterPage for this web to include jQuery and my custom JS file. I would store the jQuery Lib and my JS file in style library on the same SiteCollection. To include JS files you need to add this kind of lines:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/JavaScriptFiles/jquery.js" Defer="true" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/JavaScriptFiles/getPageProps.js" Defer="true" runat="server" />
```

I hope this will be of any help :)

Please be aware that OOB Pages lib may have different name in SharePoint depending on the language You use.

Please be aware that in order for this REST call to SharePoint API to work the user needs at least 'read' permission to this list/lib which is in the rest call, but assuming Your users will be able to enter the page then for sure they will have 'read' permission to the lib.

Please be aware thet OOB 'contact' column in pages lib has many fields (mail, name etc.) which are already present in REST API response and You don't need to use 'expand' on the call. So maybe You can use only this call:

```
_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items(" + _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId + ')
```

I only added this 'expand' to my post in order to show You how to get user object details from custom user column added to the list.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Unfortunately I'm not a developer and can only copy JavaScripts I find online that may work and hope for the best! I will try this at work tomorrow and see what happens. Dumb question...I can access the html code so where exactly do I enter the JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry Adam. I just read the script properly and can see that the JavaScript is in the footer. I look forward to trying it out because this footer issue has been driving me crazy. Thanks again. :-)

Comment: Ye sure... You may always add this js directly to HTML between <script> tags.. just remember to also include reference to jQuery  lib otherwise the $ symbol will be undefined